# Handling googlemaps markers with Angular/Ionic

Tags: angular, google-maps, markers, ionic4

I'm trying to load googlemaps markers and after clicking one of them show some info in a new page with Ionic 4. 
So, I show the markers with a for loop and subscribe to a click event. Is this the best aproach to do that?

Also, this code is not working as expected. After clicking the info is not passing properly to the other component. I'm passing the info with a service.
And I'm using the ionic-native-google-maps module. Can you give some guide?
Thanks in advance

To load the markers:

```js
public placeMarkers(markers: MarkerOptions[]) {

    for (let moptions of markers) {
      this.map.addMarkerSync(moptions).on(GoogleMapsEvent.MARKER_CLICK)
      .subscribe( (moptions) => {
        this.markersService.markerSelected.emit(moptions);
        this.router.navigate(['/placeDetails']);
       });
    }
  }
```

In the other component:

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.markersService.markerSelected.subscribe(
      (marker: MarkerOptions) => console.log(marker)
    );
  }
```

In the service:

```js
markerSelected = new EventEmitter<MarkerOptions>();
```

Comment: I used JavaScript API on my Ionic app and marker creation and click handlers worked well. Moreover, you have a very complete documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Augustin